# How can I avoid an if/else in TypeScript with mocha and undefined returns?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai

A spline that can be reticulated and return another spline. Most of the time at least.

```js
export default class Spline {
  public reticulatedCount: number;

  constructor(parent?: Spline) {
    this.reticulatedCount = parent && parent.reticulatedCount + 1 || 0;
  }

  public reticulate(): Spline | undefined {
    return new Spline(this);
  }
}
```

```js
import { assert, expect } from 'chai';
import Spline from '../src/spline';

describe("Spline", () => {
  const spline = new Spline();

  it("returns a new spline", () => {
    const reticulatedSpline = spline.reticulate();
    expect(reticulatedSpline).to.not.be.null;
    expect(reticulatedSpline.reticulatedCount).to.eq(1);
  });
});
```

Fails with `error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

```
/Users/dblock/source/ts/typescript-mocha/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:245
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
test/spline.spec.ts:18:12 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

18     expect(reticulatedSpline.reticulatedCount).to.eq(1);
```

The workaround is an anti-pattern in tests, an `if`.

```js
  it("returns a new spline", () => {
    const reticulatedSpline = spline.reticulate();
    if (reticulatedSpline) {
      expect(reticulatedSpline.reticulatedCount).to.eq(1);
    } else {
      expect(reticulatedSpline).to.not.be.null;
    }
  });
```

How can this be solved without disabling `strictNullChecks`?

Code in https://github.com/dblock/typescript-mocha-strict-null-checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `non-null` (`!`) operator.

```
it("always can be reticulated again", () => {
  const reticulatedSpline = spline.reticulate();
  expect(reticulatedSpline).to.not.be.null;
  expect(reticulatedSpline!.reticulatedCount).to.eq(1);
});
```

As the documentation says:

> [You] may be used to assert that its operand is non-null and non-undefined in contexts where the type checker is unable to conclude that fact

[Source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html)

Comment: Yes, but this shouldn't be necessary. I guess another way to phrase my question is how can we make `expect(reticulatedSpline).to.not.be.null;` to behave like an `if` as far as TypeScript is concerned and/or help the typechecker detect this?

Comment: Ok, so what you would like to happen is not to need to modify the line `expect(reticulatedSpline.reticulatedCount).to.eq(1);` since you have already validated that `reticulatedSpline` is not null with the previous assert. Because if this is the case, then the issue is that the compiler can't infer this from the assertion. You have to help it somehow. And you can do this using the `non-null` operator or typecasting the `reticulatedSpline` variable to a Spline with `reticulatedSpline as Spline`.

Comment: Why can't it infer it? The assertion ultimately raises an exception on a `null`. Is this a bug/feature request to TS?

Comment: I say it can't infer it because whose doing the assertion is `mocha` in its way. But you could propose it, though I don't think its going to fly.

Comment: So currently the options are to do `const reticulatedSpline = spline.reticulate() as Spline`, to use `!` or to check explicitly, to define a helper:

```
function expectNotNull(value: any) {
  if (value) {
    return value;
  } else {
    expect(value).to.not.be.null;
  }
}
```
and use it with `const reticulatedSpline = expectNotNull(spline.reticulate());`.

I think this answer (use `!`) is the most elegant so far.

Answer (score 1):

Updated example for Typescript 3.7 which introduced "assertion signatures":

```js
/**
 * Use in place of `expect(value).to.exist`
 *
 * Work-around for Chai assertions not being recognized by TypeScript's control flow analysis.
 * @param {any} value
 */
export function expectToExist<T>(value: T): asserts value is NonNullable<T> {
  expect(value).to.exist;
  if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    throw new Error('Expected value to exist');
  }
}
```

**References:**

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

Comment: Not a big fan of workarounds, but this seems like a particularly clean one. Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

Because `.to.not.be.null` doesn't affect code flow in these examples, TS can't currently infer that it makes changes to params passed into it. There is a code-flow dependent way to do this using [user-defined type guards](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html#user-defined-type-guards).

```
function assertNotNull<T>(v: T | null): v is NonNullable<T> {
    if (!v) throw new Error();
    return true
}

declare const maybeAString: string | undefined

function ex() {
    // Doesn't work because TS has no way to know that this will throw
    assertNotNull(maybeAString)
    maybeAString

    // Control flow analysis knows that this function will validate that maybeAString is definitely not null
    if(assertNotNull(maybeAString)) {
        maybeAString // now definitely a string
    }

    // control flow analysis knows that the branch where maybeAString isn't not null (aka is null) returns, so the main path must be non-null
    if(!assertNotNull(maybeAString)) return

    maybeAString // now definitely a string
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-dLjqqVaYNDBMtlchAADQwCBfUK9YZwSgwAAOYODw3udTFBSK601-h1KP1GiNQXjOTA2NwJTEQA)